# conversion of array based on key in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, nested

I have object like this,

```
var object1= { arun={[birthdate=21-02-1995,age=12, height=4.3, weight= 44],
                     [birthdate=21-02-1995,age=21, height=6.2, weight= 65]  },

              smita={[birthdate=19-08-1995,age=13, height=5.4, weight= 41],
                     [birthdate=19-08--1995,age=23, height=6.3, weight= 59] },

              nikita={[birthdate=16-08-1995, age=12, height=4.3, weight= 46],
                      [birthdate=16-08-1995, age=26, height=5.3, weight= 48] }
}
```

and another array like this,
`var array1=[arun, smita]` or like this `var array1=[arun]`

I'm trying to convert this object1 into like this if one name is selected

```
var object1=[{birthdate=21-02-1995, name=arun, height=[4.3,6.2]},
         {birthdate=21-02-1995, name=arun, age=[12,21]},
         {birthdate=21-02-1995, name=arun, weight=[44,65]} ]
```

and if two are selected,

```
var object1=[ {birthdate=21-02-1995, name=arun, height=[4.3,6.2]},
         {birthdate=21-02-1995, name=arun, age=[12,21]},
         {birthdate=21-02-1995, name=arun, weight=[44,65]},
         {birthdate=19-08-1995,name=smita, height=[5.4,6.3]},
         {birthdate=19-08-1995,name=smita, age=[13,23],
         {birthdate=19-08-1995,name=smita, weight=[41,59]} ]
```

Note: I'm using switch case to select the names.

I tried like this to select according to keys

```
let value=[];
value.push(array1.map((key) => {
    for(let data of object1[key]){
     xValue.push(data.height);
     yValue.push(data.age)
        } 
var result={
 name:  key,
 x: xValue,
 y: yValue,
}
return result; } ));
```

Comment: All of these objects throw errors.

Comment: [Object basics *MDN*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Objects/Basics)

Comment: please add the existing object.

Comment: existing object in the sense?

Answer (score 0):

something like this?

```
Object.entries(object1).filter((v) => ['arun', 'smita'].indexOf(v[0])).map((v) => v[1])
```